# I need a function that will compare fields and output only the fields that match all 3 criteria that needs to be met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file which has 6 columns (A,B,C) same format as columns (D,E,F)

just lacking some infomation in columns (D,E,F):

**Company Name (A,D) | Contact Name (B,E)  | Customer Type (C,F)**

What I want to do is create a VLOOKUP or IF statement that will compare the Company Name, Contact Name, and Customer Type to the corresponding columns (D,E,F).

1) If they match 100% I would like to have an added column/columns or extra sheet that will show all 3 criteria matching.

2)If they do not match then I would also like an extra excel sheet basically doing the same thing, but if this cannot be accomplished #1 would be just as good.

Thanks

Comment: So what's your current `vlookup`?

Comment: looking for the whole columns or just checking the actual line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should work:

```
=IF(AND(A:A=D:D,B:B=E:E,C:C=F:F),"Match","No Match")
```

Then you could easily filter the data for Match and then copy/paste. Otherwise, you would need to write a macro to loop through and add to either sheet.